# Error Message saying XML is invalid on SharePoint master page

Tags: html, xml, sharepoint, branding

I am branding SharePoint and when I upload the master page I get an error that says

> The 'html' start tag on line 162 position 2 does not match the end tag
>   of 'head'. Line 171, position 3.

So I check my html file and I can't seem to find what's wrong. Here is the html: https://codeshare.io/GbvxJV

Comment: For questions specific to the SharePoint platform, please move this question over to the [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed your XML file and find out below bugs:

- You need to add `<html>` tag below `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag.
- The second change is, you need to complete your `<head>` tag (before `<body>` tag starts) at line number 162, as suggested in error as well.
- There are lots of `<SPM>` tag that are spit in multiple lines. They need to be in single line.

When I make these changes, I was able to convert your HTML file to Master Page.